# Why does the likelihood of ML ancestral states change when tree is scaled?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, genetics, brownian-motion, phylogeny

I realize this might not be the best place to have this question answered, but I figured I'd try anyway. My question concerns the calculation of log likelihoods for ancestral state estimates using the maximum likelihood Brownian motion model from `ace` in the `ape` package. My understanding is that scaling all the branches of the phylogeny by a constant should not change the log likelihood of the maximum likelihood ancestral states (why would it?). However, look what happens when I compare the log likelihoods of ML ancestral states for the same data and tree, except in the second model the branches of the tree have all been multiplied by 2:

```
# Load packages and set seed
library(ape)
library(geiger)
library(phytools)
set.seed(23)

# Generate trees
tree <- rcoal(20)
tree2 <- tree
tree2$edge.length <- tree2$edge.length*2

# Generate data
data <- fastBM(tree)

# Check log likelihoods of ML ancestral state estimates
ace(data, tree, method="ML")$loglik
ace(data, tree2, method="ML")$loglik
```

The log likelihoods are clearly different, it has approximately doubled in the model with branch lengths doubled (13.18 versus 26.35). If I compare the log likelihoods of Brownian motion models fit to the data and trees using the `fitContinuous` function from the `geiger` package, the log likelihoods are exactly the same (3.73) as I would expect.

```
# Check log likelihoods of BM model fit
logLik(fitContinuous(tree, data))
logLik(fitContinuous(tree2, data))
```

So what is going on with the log likelihoods from ML ancestral states estimated in `ace`? Why do they change when the tree is simply scaled up or down without changing the relationships among taxa?